# How can I login outside the dashboard?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

[image: Login in dashboard]

I created a layout component that receives the routes, but I am not able to leave the login separate from the dashboard

Routes

```
function AppRouter() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/dashboard" />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
      <Route path="/bookings" element={<Bookings />} />
      <Route path="/sell-car" element={<SellCar />} />
      <Route path="/settings" element={<Settings />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default AppRouter;
```

Layout

```
const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div className="layout">
      <Sidebar />
      <div className="main__layout">
        <TopNav />
        <div className="content">
          <AppRouter />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Comment: What does "login separate from the dashboard" mean? What is the issue? Are you wanting to render the `<Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />` route ***not*** in the layout?

Comment: The login is inside the dashboard as in the image above

Comment: The login and dashboard are two ***different*** routes, they aren't rendered at the same time. What you describe doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm importing the layout into app
`import Layout from "./components/Layout/Layout";

function App() {
  return <Layout />;
}

export default App;
`

Comment: I don't know what I can do, should I create a different route component just for login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to render the `Login` component and route on its own *outside* the layout then the code needs a bit of a refactor.

Convert `Layout` into a layout route component that renders an `Outlet` for nested routes.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div className="layout">
      <Sidebar />
      <div className="main__layout">
        <TopNav />
        <div className="content">
          <Outlet />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Render a layout route and un-nest the `"/login"` route.

```
function AppRouter() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/dashboard" replace />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      ... other routes without layout ...
      <Route element={<Layout />}>
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="/bookings" element={<Bookings />} />
        <Route path="/sell-car" element={<SellCar />} />
        <Route path="/settings" element={<Settings />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        ... other routes with layout ...
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Depending on how much of the sidebar or topnav/header, etc you want to render with each route you might need to further split the `Layout` component's UI into further layouts that can be conditionally applied via layout routes.

For more details see [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes).